# How to check how many milliseconds my server is behind?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I usually get a warning when the server starts running 3-4 sec behind and I had to kill most of the livestock in order to reduce the lag, but I'm curious if there is a server command to check how many ticks/ms behind is the server?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to check your ticks per second in vanilla minecraft. Running `/debug start` followed by `/debug stop` after a few seconds will create a debug log file with time stamps. This is fairly inaccurate so your best bet would be with a spigot or bukkit server. On one of those servers you can use the command `/tps` to see all sorts of different stats about the ticks per second.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't know anything about bukkit or spigot, is it possible to upgrade my server to any of them?

Comment: @NikolayDyankov Certainly, just head over to https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/buildtools/ and follow the instructions on creating a server jar. From there you can just run it like a normal minecraft server